# Show design if Dataset not returns any row in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I've designed my `SSRS Report` like below,

Where **First row, Third row and Fifth row** has default value so I have used it as **Header part** for this `tablix`.

[image]

Now, the question is - when I run this report, it prompts to enter one number to get result. But if dataset does not returns any rows then I just want to show designed header part only? But currently it is not showing anything. What could be the problem or any solution to get only designed header part?

Please help me!

**Note:** *When it returns the rows it is showing Records as well as designed header part also.*

Comment: So For that you have to remove those header from grouping.

Comment: I've deleted the header from grouping but now it will not show the records even dataset returns rows... :( Or should I play with two different tablix and show /hide based `countrows`?

Comment: Thanks @Manoj for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tried to achieve this by many ways, it was working fine in `Report Builder 3.0` but when I run this report in `IE,Firefox,Chrome` browser it was not showing designed report tablix. If there would be data it will show whole report with designed header part as well as data.

*1.* I have created Two `Tablix` inside one `SubReport`-

- **First tablix**

  Just for design. (Without data part)
- **Second tablix**

  Contains both `Header` part as well as `Data` part.

Then I have Set visibility based on `CountRows("Dataset")` to show/hide `Tablix1` and `Tablix2`.
It was working fine in `Report Builder 3.0` but not in browser.

*2.* This one is the final option that I have tried and I achieved my goal with this way.

I have created two `SubReport`.

- **1 SubReport:**

  Only designed part (Without data part)
- **2 SubReport:**

  Which contains both Header Part as well as Data Part.

Then, I have added two Rows inside my `Main report Tablix`. and added both reports to different row.

Then, On `Row Visibility` I have checked `=IIF(CountRows("Dataset")>0,True,False)`

***And it's working fine now in all browsers as well.***

Answer (score 0):

You have to add headers `Outside Group` in following:

[image]

Comment: let's say I have added `Outside Group -Above` but what about 3rd and 5th row headers? as per suggesting answer, it would display only first row as header if there is no data. But I wanted to show other rows also.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!